# Discord Bot: Want to make a channel which only admins and one user can talk in

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a discord bot which will create a channel called `ticket-####` (with #### being 4 random digits) which only the user who triggered the command and the admins in the server to be able to read and speak in. Also, I want there to be a command which will delete that channel. I am using the latest version of discord.js. You can find my code at https://glitch.com/edit/#!/glitchy-discord

Thank you for your time!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You can post a question if you need help with something and provide your own code along with the error.

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti i did, i supplied the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily.

Using GuildChannelManager.
You get this from having your guild and typing `.channels`

```js
message.guild.channels
```

Then you use the create method to create the channel:

```js
message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000)}`, {
  type: 'text',
  permissionOverwrites: [
     {
       id: message.author.id,
       allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
    {
      id: message.guild.roles.cache.get('ADMIN ID');
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
    {
      id: message.guild.id
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
  ],
})
```

`Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000)` generates the random ID.

Comment: Sorry if I am being a bit irritating, i'm new to JS! But is there a way to send the text after the command +create and post that into the new channel? For example +create Hello World, and the text  Hello World do be posted in the channel? Tysm!